# Xamarin.Forms.Maps what are "Degrees of Latitude" and how are they used in the context of the MapSpan class?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms.maps

I use Xamarin.Forms.Maps and there's something I don't understand.
I'm using `MapSpan` and it's asking for `degrees of latitude and longitude` and I have no idea what they are. I looked online to try to understand but I got even more confused.

My question is, are these degrees, when added to the `MapSpan` constructor as such:

```
// the first 10 being the degree of latitude
// the second one the degree of longitude
MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 10, 10);
```

Does it mean that the map will have its `Maps.VisibleRegion` and display an amount of `Pins` to the equivalent of 10 degrees of lat and long, or 69 miles around the user ?

The thing that confuses me the most is that the `Maps.VisibleRegion` returns a `LatitudeDegrees` and a `LongitudeDegrees`, should it be used to figure out how many `Pins` to display to the user ? Or asked a different way, could these degrees load more pins outside of the user's screen because of the degree given ?

Comment: The world is a sphere (approximately). latitude and longitude are angles that describe where a point on the surface of the world is located. A map is drawn on a 2D plane. A map is always a distorted view of the world.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for it. But would you know about this part: "`Does it mean that the map will have its Maps.VisibleRegion and display an amount of Pins to the equivalent of 10 degrees of lat and long, or 69 miles around the user ?`" because that's the one that confuses me the most.